# conversion from stratonovich SDE to Ito's form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

conversion of stratonovich SDE to Ito SDE (Where $\partial$ is differential in the stratonovich form and $d$ is in ito's form):
 $$\partial X_t=\sigma(X_t,t)\partial B_t+b(t,X_t)\partial t$$.
Conversion to ito's form :
$$dX_t=b(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t,t)dB_t+c(X_t,t)dt$$
where $$c_i(X_t,t)=\frac{1}{2} \sum \sum \sigma_{j,k}(X_t,t)\frac {\partial \sigma_i,_k} {\partial x_j} (X_t,t)$$.

i calculated it using $$ \sigma(X_t,t) \partial B_t=\sigma (X_t,t)dB_t+1/2d\sigma(X_t,t)dB_t$$.
how to proceed further